# Flutter TabBarView children: single instance for screens

Tags: dart, flutter

I am experimenting with Flutter and I have created a simple TabBarView based app.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: choices.length,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: const Text('My Cool App'),
            bottom: new TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
                return new Tab(
                  text: choice.title,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
              return new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: myScreen,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is that every time I switch tab and return back, I get a new instance of myScreen.

I tried declaring myScreen as final outside the class, but it doesn't make a difference.

Any way I could achieve this?

Comment: I think you should just change your code so that it doesn't matter if you get a new instance or not.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you think I should transfer all the state from myScreen to it's containing widget ?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: Take a look at PageStorage: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html